# How to fix Service Fabric Health Error "Entity not found in Health Store."

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have hosted the service fabric application in local cluster. One of the service in the application has  health state as "error" in service fabric explorer.

The event field says

```
'MyApplication' reported Error for property 'BoundedContextRegistration'.
System.Fabric.FabricException: Entity not found in Health Store. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071C17
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricHealthClient4.EndGetServiceHealth2(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
   at System.Fabric.FabricClient.HealthClient.GetServiceHealthEndWrapper(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at MyApplication2.ActivatorService.d__4.MoveNext()
```

Background Code:

```
namespace MyApplication2
{
    public class ActivatorService : ActorService
    {}
}
```

The code of actual service which has Error as its health is:

```
namespace MyApplication.Activator
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// This class represents an actor.
    /// Every ActorID maps to an instance of this class.
    /// The StatePersistence attribute determines persistence and replication of actor state:
    ///  - Persisted: State is written to disk and replicated.
    ///  - Volatile: State is kept in memory only and replicated.
    ///  - None: State is kept in memory only and not replicated.
    /// </remarks>
    [ActorService(Name = "MyApplicationActivatorActorService")]
    [StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]
    internal class Activator : Actor, IActivatorInitialize, IActor, IDestroyable, IActorManager, ILendingActivator, ICommandHandler
    {
```

I could not find the reason. and understand from the microsoft documentation and other internet searches. I did restarted the machine. I undo the changes in source code and rebuild and Published again. But the health state is still error. How to find the reason for Error Health for this service "MyApplicationActivatorActorService" ?

Answer (score 0):

MyApplication2 is another service fabric application. That should be up for fixing this issue. After publishing the MyApplication2 service fabric application the health state is OK